# Fix the structure of the SSRS Matrix

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have been working on a small project. I am trying to display all the results in the same row without NULL values. I've written a small expression to remove the Null values already "=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!RegisterNo.Value),True,False)". However, the rows seem to be moving one level down as it is displayed in the picture ResultMatrix1. I want the results to be on the same level. Can you please tell me if this is possible and how I can achieve it. Is it something to do with the groupings or something else?

[image]

Design [Groupings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipTg4.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when you create a table, there is a Row Group called "Details" that is not actually grouped by anything. This causes it to produce one row for each row from the dataset. Since you are trying to group these, you need to make sure that innermost group is grouped by your Staff Ref No.

In the lower-right cell, you may need to change the expression to use a `Max` function. This will simply avoid arbitrarily showing blanks when they happen to be sorted before a real value within that group.